# Many to Many Relationship Tag matching?

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have an art site. I need to show related art pieces now. I have 3 tables:

```
art_info             : art_id, title  
art_tag_relationship : art_id, tag_id  
art_tags             : tag_id, tag (in text)
```

**I'm trying to get the related art for a given piece of art sorted by most relevant tag matches.**

So now lets say I have 5 art pieces with tags

art #1 tags: red, blue, green, yellow
art #2 tags: red, orange, purple, black, yellow, blue
art #3 tags: red
art #4 tags: blue, green
art #5 tags: white, brown

So now I want to get the most related art pieces to art #1 in order of most matching to least matching. I'm looking to get results like this

Related art to #1:

- Best match = art #2 (because it matched 3 tags)
- 2nd match = art #4 (because it matched 2 tags)
- 3rd match = art #3 (because it matched 1 tag)
- Do not display art #5 because no matches were found.

*I was thinking of using a foreach statement once I get the tags for art#1, but that seems inefficient.*

Here is the query I used to get the tags for art #1

```
SELECT art_info.art_id, art_info.title
FROM art_info
INNER JOIN art_tag_relationship ON art_info.art_id = art_tag_relationship.art_id
WHERE art_tag_relationship.art_id = '1'
```

So now once I have the 4 tags from art #1, how do I get the most art that has the most related tags?

Thank you for your time and use of brain.

EDIT: Concept seems to be, get the tags for art #1 through art_tag_relationship -> art_tags,  then get art_id from art_tag_relationships where tag_id's are the same from the found tags for art_id #1 in art_tag_relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the most relevant art piece, given another art_id.

```
SELECT 
    ai.art_id, 
    ai.title
    count(DISTINCT r2.tag_id) as relevance
FROM art_tag_relationship r1 
INNER JOIN art_tag_relationship r2 ON (r1.tag_id = r2.tag_id 
                                   AND r1.art_id <> r2.art_id) 
INNER JOIN art_info ai ON (r2.art_id = ai.art_id) 
WHERE r1.art_id = '1'   -- this is the art_id results should be related to. 
GROUP BY ai.art_id
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Absolutely beautiful thank you!!!! I've never seen the <> in use before. I'll read up more on this. Thanks again!

Comment: @Darius "<>" means not equal to.

Comment: Hey johan, I was a little overexcited, it seemed it was working but when I tested it out, turns out it's counting something totally different from matching tags. I searched a art_id with 4 tags , and it gave me relevance of 9. I don't understand what it is counting at this point because art with the highest relevance had no tags in common to the art I was comparing it to. Any ideas? I suspect the count it did was the count of how many art photos use the same tag, but not how many matches it made.

Comment: @Darius, Edited the query to only count distinct tags.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the piece of art you are looking at is `art_id = 1000`

```
SELECT 
    art_info.art_id, 
    art_info.title
    count(*) as Cnt
FROM 
    art_tag_relationship A1, 
    art_tag_relationship A2,
    art_info 
WHERE 
    A1.art_id = 1000 
    AND
    A1.tag_id = A2.tag_id 
    AND
    A2.art_id = art_info.art_id
GROUP BY 
    art_info.art_id
ORDER BY 
    Cnt DESC
```

(untested)

In theory, it will start with all of the tags of the art that you are looking at.  Then it will expand to match all related tags for other art pieces.  Then it will group this by the resulting art_id, and the number of records condensed into each group should equal the number of tags that matched, which is then sorted on.

Play around with the concept and update your post once you have a working query.

Comment: Using this concept. That means when a member submits some tags, I'll run a foreach statement to separate each word, check if it exists in the tags. If it exists, use an existing tag_id to link in the art_tags_relationship table and if the word doesn't exist, enter it into the art_tags table?

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to do as we expected it to do, find the tags and then find others matching it. It keeps it stuck to art_id = 1000. So it only gives me results for art_id 1000 and won't show me any other art_id's.